# Need to show vat number on stripe email receipt

Tags: stripe-payments

I am changing to users with stripe subscription API.
I need to show VAT number on stripe email receipt. 
Please suggest me a way to show VAT number on email receipt.

Comment: i think you should check @ywain's answer its true

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's built-in [email receipts](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/receipts) are not very customizable. If you want to include information other than what Stripe will let you customize, you'll likely need to disable the built-in receipts, and build your own receipts using [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

That said, this is not really a good question for StackOverflow and I recommend that you reach out to Stripe's support directly at https://support.stripe.com/email instead.

Comment: I disagree. I came to StackOverflow specifically for the answer to this question. It's very general and applies to thousands if not millions of internet businesses. Stripe is a company, but it's also an API that serves a critical role in online commerce!

Comment: Is still not supported in 2021? Basically every EU business need to add the VAT number in the invoice header. How do you solve?

Comment: I would also like to see this question answered on stackoverflow!